# What is the difference between three types of declaration of array list and why we write the interface first then on other side implementing class?

Tags: java

I have two basic questions.

1. When we write the declaration of ArrayList as

   a) `List l = new ArrayList<String>();`
   b) `List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();`
   c) `List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();`

   I saw all the above statements don't give any error. What is the difference between those variations?
2. When we initialise the collections as

   p) `List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();`

   so if we declare like below

   q) `ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();`

   What is the difference between "p" and "q", and why we choose mostly "p" while using collections?

Comment: Read up on the Liskov Principle. Coding to interfaces give you the build you applications in a plug-and-play fashion.

Comment: "*`a)List l=new ArrayList<Int>(); b)List<Int> l=new ArrayList<Int>(); c)List<Int> l=new ArrayList<>();`*" - None of those will compile; there is no class called `Int` in Java. --- Please read: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) --- A lot of developers write something like `List<Foo> l = new ArrayList<>();`. In many cases, this is unnecessary abstraction (especial on local variables). I would suggest to replace it with `ArrayList<Foo> l = new ArrayList<>();`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**a)**
`List l = new ArrayList<String>();` is the same as `List<Object> l = new ArrayList<String>();`. It means that the variable `l` is a list that can store any `Object`, but not only a String. Also you will need to cast the values of the list if you want to use them as Strings. So the **following code would compile** (which is usually not what you want):

```
List l = new ArrayList<String>();
l.add("a string");//adding a String type is what is expected here
l.add(42);//adding an int is not realy expected here, but works
l.add(new Date());//also adding any other object is allowed

String s = (String) l.get(0);//s will be "a string"
String s2 = (String) l.get(1);//runtime error, since 42 can't be cast into a String
```

**b)**
`List<String> l=new ArrayList<String>();` means, that the variable `l` is a list of Strings and will only accept String values. The **following code would cause compiler errors:**

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
l.add("a string");//adding a String type is what is expected here
l.add(42);//compiler error
l.add(new Date());//compiler error
```

**c)**
`List<String> l=new ArrayList<>();` is basically the same as `List<String> l=new ArrayList<String>();`. The diamond operator `<>` just means that it should be clear to the compiler, which type is used here, so the programmer can be lazy and let the compiler do the work.

---

**p)**
`List<String>l = new ArrayList<String>();` tells the compiler, that l is of type [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html). So if you want to assign an `ArrayList` to the variable l, that is allowed, and if you then decide, that a `LinkedList` is better, you can still assign a `LinkedList` and it will still work, because `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` both implement the interface `List`. So the **follwing code will work**:

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
//later on you decide to change the type (maybe for a better performance or whatever)
l = new LinkedList<String>();
//use the List l like nothing has changed. You just don't need to care.
```

**q)**
`ArrayList<String> l= new ArrayList<String>();` means, that the variable `l` is an `ArrayList` and can never be any other `List` implementation (like a `LinkedList`), so you can't change the implementation easily. Therefore the following code will not compile:

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
//later on you decide to change the type (maybe for a better performance or whatever)
l = new LinkedList<String>();//compiler error; now you need to change many parts of your code if you still want to change the type of l to a LinkedList
```

Therefore usually **p** is the better solution, because you can change the code easily. Only of you need to call methods that are not part of the [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface, like the [trimToSize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#trimToSize()) method of `ArrayList` it can be needed to use **q**. But that's a very rare case.

---

**Summary:**

In almost every case it's better to use **p** than **q**.
Also in almost every case it's better to use **b** or **c** than **a**. Whether you use **b** or **c** doesn't realy matter that much. **c** is just a bit shorter.

Comment: `List l = new ArrayList<String>(); is the same as List<Object> l = new ArrayList<String>()` This is NOT correct! `List` is called a *raw type*, which is different from `List<Object>`. Note how you get a raw type warning from one but not the other!

Answer (score 7):

Part 1.

> a) `List l = new ArrayList<String>();`
>
> b) `List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();`
>
> c) `List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();`

There is no difference between b) and c).

But a) declares `l` as a *raw type*.  This is discouraged.  When you use `l`, the compiler doesn't "know" what the type of the array elements will be:

- If you want to use the elements as strings you will need to cast them.
- It won't stop you putting things into the list that are not strings.  Ooops!!!

---

Part 2.

> p) `List<String>l = new ArrayList<String>();`
>
> q) `ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();`

The difference is that the type of `l` in p) says that it could be any `List` implementation, but in q) it is restricted to `ArrayList` and subtypes.

If `l` is only used locally, it probably makes little difference.  But if `l` is part of your API, or if if you need to assign `l` a different `List` value, you can run into problems.  For example, when you call `List.sublist` on an `ArrayList`, the object you get back is not an `ArrayList`!

So ... as a general rule p) is better.

In general, it is better to "program to an interface" (i.e. p) rather than an implementation (i.e. q).

Comment: and if you need to call a method on the implementation you can always cast it `((ArrayList<String>)l).trimToSize();`

Answer (score 3):

With a) you declare a List of `Object` by `List l`. With b) and c) you declare a List of `String` by `List<String> l`. With the generic operator `<type>` introduced with Java 5 the compiler is able the validate assigned instances. Compiled code works without these types, effect called *type errasure*.

No error by compiler for this example

```
List l = new ArrayList<String>();
l.add("a");
l.add(new Integer(1));
```

Error by compiler for this example

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
l.add("a");
l.add(new Integer(1));  // forces compiler error
```

Difference between b) and c): at c) you are using Diamond  operator `<>`  ( since Java 7) for which you do not need repeat the type of generic.

And for p) and q): you should use p) because `List` is an interface implemented by `ArrayList` and you could change type of used `List` implementation with lesser changes.

Answer (score 3):

Your (b) and (c) items are identical.

A later version of Java enabled the compiler to [infer the parameterized type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) on the right from the declaration on the left. So (c) became a convenient shortcut for (b). I cannot imagine a situation where you would not choose (c) over (b).

In contrast, your (a) is very much different.

When you omit the parameterized type from the left side, you deny the compiler a chance the verify type-safety of objects being added to the collection. Your collection on the left is known as *raw*.

In your example, your intention is to allow only `String` objects to be added to the collection. But with a raw collection, any object can be added. Here is example code where I add a `DayOfWeek` object rather than a `String`.

```
List list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ;
```

See this [code run successfully at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/IAH9s2).

Change `List list` to `List< String > list` to see a compiler error saying you cannot fit a `DayOfWeek` into a collection for `String` objects — round hole, square peg.

The key to understanding this is [*type erasure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure). Because generics was bolted onto Java later in its life, Java generics comes with a limitation: Java only knows about the parameterized type at compile-time. At run-time, the parameterized type is lost, unknown, *erased*.

Other programming languages offer [*reified generics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_(computer_science)), meaning the parameterized type is not erased, and is known at run-time. But not so in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Since right answer is already given, I will add few things that you should keep a glimpse on the term `type erasure`. This will help you to understand the Generics mechanism.

https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/generics-java-example-tutorial.html#axzz72vrqjSEX this is a good article for understand the mechanism.

```
List l = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You have already know that this will produce raw type. But why we need raw type? Generics was introduced from `Java 5`before then a List can hold different type of values (i.e. `int`, `String`, ...). Identical as the code-snippet below:

```
    List rawList = new ArrayList(); 
    rawList.add(10);
    rawList.add("Hello");
```

After introduce of `Generics` `Java` need a option to access the old `List` which holds different types of value. That's why `raw type` exists. In short, for backwards compatibility `raw type` exists. But you shouldn't use it for future development as @Stephen C suggested. Why you shouldn't use `raw type` is because it violate the `type safety` and `Generics` introduce to enable the `type safety` feature.

Answer (score 0):

As Turing85 said, simply use `ArrayList<Foo> l = new ArrayList<>();` `List` is an interface that `ArrayList` implements. To write like `ArrayList<Foo> l = new ArrayList<Foo>()` means that you have enough time to do unnecessary things. This is like casting `int i=(int)((float)(1));` Why not just `int i=1`?